# Why could not find or load main class?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, javafx

After building the project, I found out that the application does not work on Linux. On windows everything is in order. What is the reason?

```
java -jar personnel-reserve-service-1.0.5.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class ru.iworking.personnel.reserve.ApplicationJavaFX
```

UPD:
But i see Main-Class. I have /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF where written this text:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/personnel-reserve-api-1.0.1.jar ......... lib/javassist-3.
 26.0-GA.jar lib/joda-time-2.10.6.jar
Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8
Created-By: Maven Jar Plugin 3.2.0
Main-Class: ru.iworking.personnel.reserve.ApplicationJavaFX
```

Comment: Make sure your Java version is the same in your systems. 
And try compiling the same app in Linux too.

Comment: fact that you have name of class in manifest does not mean it must exists. try `unzip -l personnel-reserve-service-1.0.5.jar` to see actual content of jar

Comment: It is a bit odd that you are using joda-time in Java 8.  You should be able replace joda-time usage with corresponding in Java 8+ `java.time` classes.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my problem - reinstall openJdk. I loaded JFX package from [AZUL](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?architecture=x86-64-bit)